# Basic Kibana/Elasticsearch Search - Powershell

Tags: web-scraping, powershell, rest

I am traditionally a Java/Backend Developer, and have recently been spending a lot of time dealing with issues that higher tiers of support should be able to handle themselves. To assist them with this, I wrote the following script for them to extract what look like "Log Files" from Kibana, allowing them to do some Analysis before issues get sent down to me.

While this will not be "production" code, it will probably be used as a tool internally, so I would like it to be as complete as possible for use.

Here is the group of scripts:

`Script:`

```
# Function defenition, allows us to call this as a CmdLet 
function Search-Kibana-Request {
    [CmdletBinding()] 

    # Parameters required by the Kibana Request Search Script
    Param (
        [Parameter(
            Position = 0, 
            Mandatory = $true, 
            HelpMessage = "A Request ID that was pulled from a HAR or Chrome Dev Tools"
        )]
        [Alias("RequestId")]
        [String]$REQUEST_ID,

        [Parameter(
            Position = 1, 
            Mandatory = $false,
            HelpMessage = "Number of days in the past to search within; defaults to 7 days"
        )]
        [int]$DAYS_TO_SEARCH = 7,

        [Parameter(
            Position = 2, 
            Mandatory = $false,
            HelpMessage = "Number of results to be returned by the search, default limited to 500"
        )]
        [int]$SEARCH_RESULT_LIMIT = 500
    )

    # Set the script variables we will be using
    $script:startDateUnixEpoch = ([DateTimeOffset](Get-Date).ToUniversalTime()).ToUnixTimeMilliseconds()
    $script:endDateUnixEpoch = ([DateTimeOffset](Get-Date).AddDays($DAYS_TO_SEARCH * -1).ToUniversalTime()).ToUnixTimeMilliseconds()
    $script:indexSearchURL = 'https://<KIBANA_HOST>/elasticsearch/us1-wfoadapter-*/_field_stats?level=indices'
    $script:queryURL = 'https://<KIBANA_HOST>/elasticsearch/_msearch'
    $script:headers = @{'kbn-xsrf' = 'reporting'}
    $script:totalIndicies = 0
    $script:partitionSize = 5
    $script:logText = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[System.Object]

    # Ensure we are using the right version of TLS for the web requests
    [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12

    # First, get the list of indicies that contain the timeframe we are searching;  
    # this prevents us from searching all indexes on the server
    $body = @{
        'fields' = @("@timestamp")
        'index_constraints' = @{
            '@timestamp' = @{
                'max_value' = @{
                    'gte' = $script:endDateUnixEpoch
                    'format' = 'epoch_millis'
                }
                'min_value' = @{
                    'lte' = $script:startDateUnixEpoch
                    'format' = 'epoch_millis'
                }
            }
        }
    } | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 3 -Compress
    $indiciesResponse = (Invoke-RestMethod $script:indexSearchURL -ContentType 'application/json' -Method POST -Body $body -Headers $script:headers)

    # With the indicies response, partition the indicies into the correct query size 
    # for each batch (5), and execute the search query request for each batch
    $indiciesToSearch = Get-Member -InputObject $indiciesResponse.indices -MemberType NoteProperty
    $partitionedIndicies = $indiciesToSearch | Group-Object -Property { [math]::Floor($script:totalIndicies++ / $script:partitionSize) }
    foreach($indexGroup in $partitionedIndicies) {
        # Build the part of the query that tells the engine what indicies to search within
        $searchGroup = '"' + ($indexGroup.Group.Name -join '","') + '"'
        $queryIndexPart = "`"index`":[$($searchGroup)],`"ignore_unavailable`":true"

        # Build the part of the query that tells the engine what to search for and how to sort
        $querySortPart = "`"size`":$($SEARCH_RESULT_LIMIT),`"sort`":[{`"@timestamp`":{`"order`":`"asc`",`"unmapped_type`":`"boolean`"}}]"
        $queryCriteriaPart = "`"query`":{`"bool`":{`"must`":[{`"query_string`":{`"query`":`"message:`\`"$($REQUEST_ID)`\`"`",`"analyze_wildcard`":true}},{`"range`":{`"@timestamp`":{`"gte`":$($script:endDateUnixEpoch),`"lte`":$($script:startDateUnixEpoch),`"format`":`"epoch_millis`"}}}],`"must_not`":[]}}"

        # Combine the query parts into a single JSON type object 
        $queryString = "{$($queryIndexPart)}`r`n{$($querySortPart),$($queryCriteriaPart)}`r`n"

        # Execute the query against the indexes that were returned previously
        $queryResponse = (Invoke-RestMethod $script:queryURL -ContentType 'application/json' -Method POST -Body $queryString -Headers $script:headers)

        # Gather all of the responses that have hits
        $queryHits = $queryResponse.responses.hits
        if($queryHits.total -ne 0) {
            foreach($hit in $queryHits.hits) {
                $script:logText.Add($hit._source.message)
            }
        }
    }

    # Output the log lines that were returned by the query
    Write-Output $script:logText
}
```

I have them installing this script for use with the following, which does not seem completely safe.

`Install:`

```
# Install the function to the user's profile by appending to the end of the file
$hasUserProfile = Test-Path $Profile -PathType Leaf
if($hasUserProfile -ne $True) {
    New-Item -Path $Profile -ItemType File -Force
}
$source = 'U:\Development\EmployeeTemp\<ME>\UsefulScripts\KibanaSearch\KibanaSearchRequest.ps1'
$content = [IO.File]::ReadAllText($source)
Add-Content $Profile "`r`n$($content)`r`n"

# Ensure we tell the user things have been installed
Write-Output "Search-Kibana-Request successfully installed! Press any key to continue..."
$null = $Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey('NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown');
Start-Process PowerShell
Stop-Process -Id $PID
```

Finally, I have them running the function as follows:

`Search-Kibana-Request 1234-1234-1234-1234 > log.dbg`

I know there are issues with the install script, but if anyone can  point anything else out, that would  be helpful.